# Computing $\lim (^{nk}C_n)^{\frac 1n}$ using series expansion

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to compute $\lim (^{nk}C_n)^{\frac 1n}$ using series expansion, where $k$ is a fixed integer greater than $1$.
This limit can be evaluated easily by recalling that if $x_n\gt 0$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$ then $(\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\to b\in \mathbb R)\implies (|x_n|^{\frac 1n}\to b) $. But I have difficulty computing the limit using series expansion. Let $x_n= ^{nk}C_n$

$^{nk}C_n=\frac{nk (nk-1)(nk-2)...(nk-(n-1))}{n!}\implies x_n^{\frac 1n}=(\frac {n^n}{n!})^{\frac 1n}(\frac kn)^{\frac 1n} \Big((k-\frac1n)(k-\frac 2n)\cdots (k-\frac{n-1}n)\Big)^{\frac 1n}$

Here $(\frac {n^n}{n!})^{\frac 1n}(\frac kn)^{\frac 1n}\to e$.

Let $y_n=\Big((k-\frac1n)(k-\frac 2n)\cdots (k-\frac{n-1}n)\Big)^{\frac 1n}\\ \begin{align}\log y_n&=\frac{(n-1)\log k+\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}\log(1-\frac r{kn})}{n}\\&=
\frac{n-1}{n}\log k-\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}(\frac r{kn^2}+\frac 12\frac{r^2}{k^2n^3})+\sum_{r=1}^{n-1} o(\frac {1}{n^2})\\&\to\log k-(\frac 1{2k}+\frac 1{6k^2})\end{align}$

Therefore, $x_n^{\frac 1n}\to e.e^{\log k-(\frac 1{2k}+\frac 1{6k^2})}=k.e^{1-(\frac 1{2k}+\frac 1{6k^2})}$

But this is wrong. I'm not sure what went wrong above. I think that the step involving little o and steps after that are wrong. Please let me know what I am missing. Thanks.

Comment: Note that, by Riemann sums, $$
\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{r = 1}^{n - 1} {\log \left( {1 - \frac{r}{{kn}}} \right)}  \to \int_0^1 {\log \left( {1 - \frac{x}{k}} \right)dx}  = (k - 1)\log \left( {1 - \frac{1}{k}} \right) - 1.
$$

Comment: @Gary write that as a answer and Koro will accept that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you expanded the logarithm you got the error term incorrectly. Each term in the expansion will have a non-zero limit as $n→+∞$. So you would need all terms. To get them in one go, you can use Riemann sums:
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{r = 1}^{n - 1} {\log \left( {1 - \frac{r}{{kn}}} \right)}  \to \int_0^1 {\log \left( {1 - \frac{x}{k}} \right)dx}  = (k - 1)\log \left( {1 - \frac{1}{k}} \right) - 1.
$$
This is consistent with Claude's answer.

Comment: I realized error in my method yesterday during our discussion in comments. Thanks.

Comment: @Koro Yes, I just wanted this question to have an answer that addresses the issue in your original derivation.

Answer (score 0):

$$A=\binom{k n}{n}^{\frac{1}{n}}=\Bigg[\frac{(k n)!}{n! (k n-n)!} \Bigg]^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
Take the logarithm
$$\log(A)={\frac{1}{n}}\log\Bigg[\frac{(k n)!}{n! (k n-n)!} \Bigg]$$ Use three times Stirling approximation
$$\log(p!)=p (\log (p)-1)+\frac{1}{2} \log (2 \pi  p)+\frac{1}{12 p}-\frac{1}{360
   p^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^5}\right)$$ and continue with Taylor expansions for large $n$. You should arrive at
$$n \,\log(A)=n (k \log (k)-(k-1) \log (k-1))+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)-\log
   (2 \pi  (k-1))\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
$$\log(A)=k \log (k)-(k-1) \log (k-1)+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ Now, use the fact that
$$A=e^{\log(A)}=\frac {k^k }{(k-1)^{k-1} }$$

Trying for $n=100$ and $k=4$, the exact value is
$9.19403$ while the final expression gives $\frac{256}{27}=9.48148$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I haven never used Stirling approximation before to solve any problem. Can you please let me know what went wrong in my method? Thanks.

Comment: Your final formula for $A$ is correct only if you define $A$ to be the limit. Otherwise you need to add a factor of $1+\mathcal{O}(1/n)$.

Comment: @Gary: any suggestions for what went wrong in my method? Thanks.

Comment: When you expanded the logarithm you got the error term incorrectly. Each term in the expansion will have a non-zero limit as $n\to +\infty$. So you would need all terms. So for the next term, you have $$
 - \sum\limits_{r = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{1}{3}\frac{{r^3 }}{{k^3 n^4 }}}  \to  - \frac{1}{{12k^3 }}.
$$

Comment: Note that, by Riemann sums, $$
\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{r = 1}^{n - 1} {\log \left( {1 - \frac{r}{{kn}}} \right)}  \to \int_0^1 {\log \left( {1 - \frac{x}{k}} \right)dx}  = (k - 1)\log \left( {1 - \frac{1}{k}} \right) - 1.
$$

Comment: @Gary: thanks a lot, you have answered my question. :)